# GPS and GIS for real time monitoring of an object

Tags: gps, geolocation

How is it possible to store coordinate of object in server in real time using feasible hardware ( can be used by student) GPS into database and retrived in real time??

1. What are the names of equipment ?
2. **Any link to good resource?**

The purpose of this experiment is to provide real time location of object through internet(web).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a smart phone with GPS to regularly upload it's location to a webserver running both PostGIS and Geoserver. You can then request real time locations through Geoserver services.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting solution i.e. easy to try out. Any pointers/ reads/ webrefs in answer to part 2?

Answer (score 2):

you may have a look at the french national geographic institute solution's, called geocube
[Geocube description's](http://recherche.ign.fr/LOEMI/pdf/brochureGeocube1.pdf) or [enter link description here](http://www.frisia-it.com/assets/images/SANY_Book.pdf) (page 55), think it's not already marketed.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easily done.  If you look at, for example, instamapper.com, they do this very thing; you send your geo location live to their application, which shows immediately on a map.  I use this on my iPhone and when I do very long rides, it allows my wife to trrack me, in order she knows how far away I am, and when to run a bath, come outside to carry me off my bike ;)

It is simply a matter of trapping the gps and there are several apps out there which can trap your devices geolocation for you.  The rest is simply about updating the database, and updating your maps.

Comment: that's great :)

Comment: ...and a careful reading of the services TOS, as to know whether they will sell your track data to the highest bidder ;)